# Crawl various websites using scrapy and find specific words

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I am new to scrapy framework. They have this great documentation where I learned about various stuffs. I am trying to curl various educational websites upto depth level 3, find cse departments(try to find cse or computer or lists of words in the links scraped on that page) in each websites. If they have cse department in their websites those links or URLs will be stored in a .csv file. Here's my code so far:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

from dirbot.items import Website


class DmozSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//ul/li')
        items = []

        for site in sites:
            item = Website()
            item['name'] = site.select('a/text()').extract()
            item['url'] = site.select('a/@href').extract()
            item['description'] = site.select('text()').extract()
            items.append(item)

        return items
```

Problem is: In allowed_domains I want to crawl more than 1000 websites which are stored in .csv file. I want to import csv file and iterate through each URLs. How can I do that? If they have cs departments those link should be written in a csv file. How can I modify my XPath to find  cse department(try to find cse or computer or lists of words in the links scraped on that page) in each websites and where do I apply condition(if the link have cse department write that link into file otherwise not.) Finally how do I specify depth in scrapy? Thanks Also is it possible to define the word search technique in a file and use it in the scrapy?

Answer (score 0):

‘start_urls‘ is just a list. Override the init, read the csv, and assemble your list.

Comment: What's allowed domains hold? Is it inbuild keyword?

Comment: The list of domains it's allowed/intended/restricted to crawl of course. Leave it out to allow all.